# Dataframes, csv, and CNTK

Tags: pandas, dataframe, cntk

I have been playing around with CNTK and am finding that models can only be trained using numpy arrays. Is this correct?

This makes sense for image recognition etc.

How would I turn my tidy dataset (read in as a dataframe using pandas) into a format that can train a logistic regression with? I have tried to read it into a numpy array

```
 np.genfromtxt(“My.csv",delimiter=',' , dtype=float)
```

and I have also tried to wrap the variable with

```
np.array.MyVeriable.astype('float32')
```

But I do not get the result I want to be able to feed a model.

I also cannot find anything in the tutorial about how to do ML on tabular dataframes in CNTK.

Is it not supported?

Answer (score 1):

CNTK 104 shows how to use pandas dataframes and numpy.

https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_104_Finance_Timeseries_Basic_with_Pandas_Numpy.ipynb

CNTK 106B shows how you could read data using csv files.

https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_106B_LSTM_Timeseries_with_IOT_Data.ipynb

Comment: If you actually look there, CNTK 106B uses df = pd.read_csv.  So your answers are actually just "1. use pandas. 2.use pandas."

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for these links. This is how I ended up reading in the csv it seemed to work but Sayan please correct as needed:

```
def generate_data_from_csv():

# try to find the data file local. If it doesn't report "file does not exists" if it does report "using loacl file"
data_path = os.path.join("MyPath")
csv_file = os.path.join(data_path, "My.csv")
if not os.path.exists(data_path):
    os.makedirs(data_path)
if not os.path.exists(data_file):
    print("file does not exists")
else:
    print("using loacl file")

df = pd.read_csv(csy_file, usecols = ["predictor1", "predictor2",
"predictor3", "predictor4", "dependent_variable"], dtype=np.float32)

return df
```

Then I saved that dataframe as training_data

```
training_data = generate_data_from_csv()
```

I then turned that dataframe into an numpy array as follows

```
training_features = np.asarray(training_data[[["predictor1",    
"predictor2", "predictor3", "predictor4",]], dtype = "float32")
training_labels = np.asarray(training_data[["dependent_variable"]],
dtype="float32")
```

The to train the model I used this code:

```
features, labels = training_features[:,[0,1,2,3]], training_labels
```